# Application Theme problem in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

I have been trying to create an App for AR Project and i got the UI Error that goes like:

> Error CS0103
> The name 'ApplicationTheme' does not exist in the current context

To combat this error i installed the UNO.UI package and used the Using Windows.UI.XAML directive

Then the error changed and turned to this:

> Error CS0117
> 'ApplicationTheme' does not contain a definition for 'BackgroundColor'

I have also attached the code so please help me with this and btw it is a xamarin.ios app

```
public override void LoadView()
{
    // Create and add the container views.
    View = new UIView() { BackgroundColor = ApplicationTheme.BackgroundColor};
             ---
             ---
}
```

Comment: [OPINION] While Uno.UI has been demonstrated with Xamarin, mainly to port UWP apps to mobile, be aware that relatively few people use that combination. I recommend going to **.net 6**, and then picking **either** Maui **or** Uno.UI. Not attempting to combine - at least not at this time. Seek out people using Uno on forums, for help with Uno.

Comment: I had checked the ` Windows.UI.XAML.ApplicationTheme` , it is a enum which has two kind values. Do you ensure the Api you want?